# what is the meaning of these terms

Tags: image-processing

I am working in digital image restoration field, recently i am studying a paper **Blur-Kernel Estimation from Spectral Irregularities**, in this paper i have got some terms, which i am unable to understand, can anyone please provide me specific description of these terms. [i have already google it, but i didn't get satisfactory answer].

**four-point Laplacian filter**

**The Wiener−Khinchin theorem**

**Power Spectrum of an image**

**autocorrelation**

**Fourier slice theorem**

Comment: try to google it

Comment: Most of these terms are covered very well in Wikipedia and elsewhere - you should probably invest a little more time and effort with your internet searches and then come back if you have any specific unresolved questions.